# Include a text file content into a WiX script

Tags: build, wix, versioning

Is there a way to read value for the WiX variable from a text file?

What I am trying to do is to include a version-specific information into instlal package.

This version information extracted into the text file on the pre-build step,
the question is how to propages this text file content into a build process.

One of the possible solution is to update whole .wxs file on the pre-build step
too, but it feel a bit sloppy.

Is there any other, less-intrusive way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a separate file 'includes.wxi', for example like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include Id="VersionNumberInclude">
    <?define MajorVersion="1" ?>
    <?define MinorVersion="5" ?>
    <?define MicroVersion="99" ?>
    <?define BuildVersion="14954" ?>
</Include>
```

In your wxs file, you can include this file like this:

```
<?include VersionNumberInclude.wxi ?>
```

And the defines can be used like this:

```
<?define VersionNumberInternal="$(var.MajorVersion).$(var.MinorVersion).$(var.BuildVersion)" ?>
<?define VersionNumberUserVisible="$(var.MajorVersion).$(var.MinorVersion).$(var.MicroVersion).$(var.BuildVersion)" ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that was exactly I was after. Very neat!

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, WiX scripts are *always* built by the MSBuild file.  That means that I can pass in any version-specific information I want on the command line.  CruiseControl.NET passes these version numbers to my WiX script when built.