# How To Run MSBuild scripts in .wixproj?

Tags: asp.net, installation, wix

Im trying to learn to make a web installer using Windows Installer XML (WIX 3.5). I found this blog about using msbuild in .wixproj files to avoid the scenario where the installer ends up dropping the web project assemblies right in the root of the app instead of keeping them in the bin folder like they're supposed to be.

Here is the link to that:
<**http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-consume-msdeploy-staged-web-site-output-in-a.aspx**>

But after adding the MSBuild scripts in the .wixproj file, I don't know what to do anymore. According to the instruction after adding the MSBuild script:

"When that target runs, you'll see a .wxs file pop out in the .wixproj project folder. Add the generated .wxs to your .wixproj project so it knows to include it in the build."

I really don7t know what this means. How can I run the target? I tried to build it but there was no .wxs file generated in the .wixproj folder.

Am I missing something? Please help...

Comment: can you post your .wixproj file? For reference, also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710687/best-way-to-create-a-wix-fragment-file-based-on-user-defined-directories-to-be-us

Comment: A wixproj is already an msbuild file so all you have to do is define another target and call it.

Comment: @Christopher: sorry Im just a newbie in WIX and msbuild. What do you mean by "define another target and call it"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added the section from the tutorial:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
...
</Target>
```

The target will be run automatically when you build the project. The "BeforeBuild" target is one of the standard entry-points to add your own modifications to the build. The target will then generate a file (named [WebProjectName].wxs that is placed in the same directory as your wixproj file. Click on the show all files button in visual studio and right-click on the file and "Include in project" That will then include the wxs is your installer and when you next build it will have the correct folder/file structure.